# Fitting custom distribution scipy.stats gives overflow

Tags: numpy, scipy, distribution, scipy.stats

I am trying to fit a generalised error distribution to some data that I have. The form of the distribution is given as
[image]

I have tried the following implementation

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.special import gamma

class ged(st.rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self, x, mu, sigma, kappa):
        
        term1 = gamma(3*kappa)/gamma(kappa)
        
        exponent = (term1 * ((x - mu)/sigma)**2)**(1/(2*kappa))
        
        term2 = np.exp(-exponent)
        
        term3 = 2*sigma*gamma(kappa+1)
        
        fx = term1**0.5 * term2/term3

        return fx

ged_inst = ged(name='ged')
data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
ged_inst.fit(data, 0, 0.01, 1)
```

However this gives

```
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

How do I correctly implement this distribution? I am trying to fit to real data (not the toy normal data generated in the question)

Comment: I believe you have to define _argcheck. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122645/fitting-a-custom-scipy-distribution/66126496#66126496 for proper custom distribution

Comment: You could put it it as an answer and I endorse it

Comment: Good idea, I've done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments, to get this working I needed to override the default `_argcheck` function. The following works:

```
class ged(st.rv_continuous):

    def _pdf(self, x, mu, sigma, kappa):
        
        term1 = gamma(3*kappa)/gamma(kappa)
        
        exponent = (term1 * ((x - mu)/sigma)**2)**(1/(2*kappa))
        
        term2 = np.exp(-exponent)
        
        term3 = 2*sigma*gamma(kappa+1)
        
        fx = term1**0.5 * term2/term3

        return fx
    
    def _argcheck(self, mu, sigma, kappa):
        
        s = sigma > 0
        k = kappa < 1
        
        return s and k
```